# How to fix "spatial_ref_sys relation does not exist"

Tags: postgis

I am trying to install postgis in my database. I compiled the library successfully. Now when I try to import the sql spatial_ref_sys is shows the error that

```
spatial_ref_sys relation does not exist
```

When I looked into the sql, it has no create table at the top. What should I do. Am I supposed to have these two tables geometry_columns and spatial_ref_sys from other sources. I just created a database mydatabase and tried to import the spatial_ref_sys.sql into it. Any suggestions? The version of my postgresql is 9.1.3 and the version of my postgis is 2.0.0

Comment: Did you execute postgis.sql first? (name might be slightly different)

Comment: Yeah I found it and it executed successfully. Thanks. However it didn't create the geometry_columns table which it was supposed to isn't it?

Comment: if it helps at all, geometry_columns is a view in 2.0, not a table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you also execute spatial_ref_sys.sql ?

Comment: Yes, I did, but it didn't create the geometry_columns table

Comment: Look through the two forementioned sql files and find where the spatial_ref_sys is being created. Is it not listed in either script? If it is, then there's an issue with the way you're running it.

Comment: This issue is fixed

Comment: Why don't you actually contribute to the collaborative solution rajan and post a tutorial

Comment: How in the world is this an answer?  It is in fact a question? "Did he go to the bathroom? would be as helpful.

Answer (score 6):

One other point that may help somebody else... Make sure you're actually in the database which has had the GIS extensions added before you try to grant privileges on it!

```
$ psql geodjango
psql (9.1.6)
Type "help" for help.

geodjango=# grant select,insert,update,delete on spatial_ref_sys to postgres;
GRANT
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to install postgis first. Then dont forget to create extension postgis on your database.

PSQL

`\c gis; --Connect to gis database
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`